# Android ThreadPoolExecutor and join()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a threadpool executor with several threads which are running concurrently. I want to execute some code after all threads have completed. How can I achieve this?

```
      for(String x : mList){
        mExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do Stuff
                            }

        });

       //after all threads finish
       doOtherStuff();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should achieve what you need:

```
for(String x : mList) {
   mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do Stuff
        }    
   });
 }

 mExecutor.shutdown();
 mExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

 //after all threads finish
 doOtherStuff();
```

Comment: Out of interest is there a reason you chose DAYS? I would have gone for milliseconds.

Comment: @JJG: I wanted to make the wait as close as possible to "indefinite waiting", so I chose the maximum values for the two parameters. It's just to make sure there is no possible way for your tasks to return before the barrier times out.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a `CountDownLatch`. Init the `CountDownLatch` with the number of thread of the executor. At the end of the `Runnable`, add `CountDownLatch.countDown();`

```
 CountDownLatch countDownL = new CountDownLatch(N);
for(String x : mList){
        mExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do Stuff
                countDownL.countDown();
            }

        });
  }

   countDownL.await();
       //after all threads finish
       doOtherStuff();
```

be aware that calling the `await()` will cause the blocker of the caller, until the `countDonwL` reach the value of 0. Of course, if you call await() on the UI thread it will block the UI.

EDIT I wrote it down before check the syntax. So some typo errors could be occur.

Comment: If you're going to use this approach, you should extend ThreadPoolExecutor and put the latch.countDown() call in the overridden afterExecute method.  I wouldn't put it in each runnable, since that would be invasive to begin with, and you'd have to make sure it's in a finally block as well.  However, i'd recommend the approach someone mentoined using shutdown() and awaitTermination().

Answer (score 0):

Using of **CountDownLatch provided in the java.util.concurrency** package will help you achieve what you need here.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
```

**This above line will create a CountDownlatch with a count of 3.**

```
latch.countDown();
```

**This above line will decrement the latch by 1 every time its execute.**

```
latch.await();
```

**This above line will let the execution of the code below it, once the Count down of latch reached 0. After this you can place the work you need to do....**